# Moshiach ben Yosef and the relation to Yaakov

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, messiah, parashat-toldot

In parashas Toldos, it is explained that Yaakov stayed in his tent, "[...] but Jacob was a mild man who stayed in camp". The Haamek Davar on this pasuk says that "his tent" or "in camp" refers to the Torah, e.g. Yaakov studied Torah while Esau was in the fields. I have a question on this pasuk, in connection to Moshiach ben Yosef. Why is Moshiach linked to Yosef and not to Yaakov, since Yaakov is connected to Torah, according to the pasuk mentioned earlier? Yaakov is mentioned in prayers etc.

The Kol HaTor [1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Kol_HaTor.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> "Moshiach ben Dovid, however, will come from Heaven as revealed by the
> different aspects of Rachel and Leah".

Here, Moshiach ben Dovid is connected to Yaakov (via Rachel and Lea), but why won't we call Moshiach after Yaakov?